# Understanding Class File: 'putfield Test.a : int [12]'

Tags: java, eclipse, class, compilation

I opened My java class file in eclipse and I have a doubt in this particular line.

```
iconst_10
putfield Test.a : int [12]
```

What does `[12]` signify? Does it signify Bytes allocated?

My java code is

```
class Test {
   public Integer a = 5;
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test t = new Test();
      t.a = 4;//This line compiles to the above code.
   }
}
```

This is javap code, but quite different from eclipse one

```
public Test();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #10; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   iconst_5
   6:   invokestatic    #12; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/In
teger;
   9:   putfield        #18; //Field a:Ljava/lang/Integer;
   12:  return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new     #1; //class Test
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #26; //Method "<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1
   8:   aload_1
   9:   iconst_4
   10:  invokestatic    #12; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/In
teger;
   13:  putfield        #18; //Field a:Ljava/lang/Integer;
   16:  return

}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to add link to IBM tutorial which explains the bytecode output with an example. Check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not bytes allocated. It is most likely the index into the constant pool for the field `Test.a`.

Comment: Cannot be. I have made more objects and every time the code for allocation is same(if it was index it cannot be same every time)

Comment: Well, having no experience with your eclipse plugin, I can't tell you. If you show me the `javap` output I might help.

Comment: It *is* a constant pool index, but for `Integer.valueOf`, a method used to convert your literal `int` into an `Integer`.

Comment: ok understood, i recompiled the class file and next this time it was [18]. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> In bytecode, the putfield opcode is followed by a 16-bit unsigned
>   integer index. This is the index of an entry in the constant pool of
>   the current class.

More info: [here](http://www.vmth.ucdavis.edu/incoming/Jasmin/ref-putfield.html)

Comment: I tried reading it but got lost in between. Can you please explain me in simple language?

Answer (score 1):

[Referring Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)

**putfield**

> set field to value in an object objectref, where the field is
>   identified by a field reference index in constant pool (indexbyte1 <<
>   8 + indexbyte2)

[IBM Java Bytecode:](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/) This link explains with an example how putfield works

> The putfield opcode pops the two top values off the stack and stores a
>   reference to strName into the instance data name of the object
>   referenced by this .

```
public Employee(String strName, int num)
{
   name = strName;
   idNumber = num;
   storeData(strName, num);
}

Method Employee(java.lang.String,int)
0 aload_0
1 invokespecial #3 <Method java.lang.Object()>
4 aload_0
5 aload_1
6 putfield #5 <Field java.lang.String name>
9 aload_0
10 iload_2
11 putfield #4 <Field int idNumber>
14 aload_0
15 aload_1
16 iload_2
17 invokespecial #6 <Method void storeData(java.lang.String, int)>
20 return
```